# Changing background image in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change my background image everytime a click a button. The problem is, I'm always getting a javanullexception.

Here is my code:

```
    public class Help extends Activity {

    int pageCtr = 0;
    RelativeLayout hLayout;
    ImageView nextbtn, prevtbtn;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

            hLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.helpLayout);
            hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg1);

     }

     public void showNextPage(View v)
     {
         pageCtr++;
         switchPage(pageCtr);
     }

     public void showPrevPage(View v)
     {
         pageCtr--;
         switchPage(pageCtr);
     }

     public void switchPage(int ctr)
     {
         hLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.helpLayout);
         nextbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
         prevtbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

         switch (ctr)
         {
         case 0:
             prevtbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg1);
             break;
         case 1:
             prevtbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg2);
             break;
         case 2:
             hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg3);
             break;
         case 3:
             nextbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg4);
             break;
         case 4:
             nextbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             hLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.helpbg5);
             break;
         }
     }

}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/helpLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/backbtn" 
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:onClick="showPrevPage"
    android:visibility="gone"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nextbtn" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:onClick="showNextPage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Stacktrace/logcat:

```
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     ... 11 more
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at com.example.gems.Help.switchPage(Help.java:53)
        01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     at com.example.gems.Help.showNextPage(Help.java:31)
    01-11 23:36:28.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1351):     ... 14 more
```

It is a simple code, but the error points at my pageCtr. It seems that it doesn't see any value of my pageCtr. Tried to pass the global variable to the method hoping it would work, but it didn't. The error is when I try to increment or decrement the pageCtr.

Comment: Paste the stacktrace please.

Comment: one of nextBtn and prevBtn is not found in your view hierarchy

Comment: quick comment : you are relying solely on the ui to ensure pageCtr stays within the right bounds (by hiding the buttons that may trigger extra changes). You risk facing issues if you change the behaviour of your UI. I recommend adding bound control to the pageCtr access.

Comment: can you give me a quick fix for my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code and layout there are differences between names :

```
android:id="@+id/backBtn"

prevtbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backbtn);
```

Also I would suggest to implement your own OnClickListener and to debug the onClick() function.

Answer (score 1):

The name of **`backBtn`** doesn't match in your java code and the xml declaration.

In **XML**, `android:id="@+id/backBtn"`

In **Java**, `prevtbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backbtn);`

You should be using :

```
public void switchPage(int ctr)
     {
         hLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.helpLayout);
         nextbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
         prevtbtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
...
}
```

Comment: I posted my xml file. I don't have problems with my buttons.

Comment: @ljpv14 Please have a look at the edit of my answer. The name of backBtn doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a reference to **hLayout** there is no need to reassign it in switchPage function.
Please check if you have both of ImageView's(nextbtn, prevtbtn) in activity_help.xml.
Also how do you call showNextPage & showPrevPage and what View do you pass there?

Comment: There's an onclick in the xml for the imageViews backBtn and nextBtn. ImageView's(nextbtn, prevtbtn) are variables in my java file.

Comment: Can you please post here your layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this steps:

1. Put your images in array. As per your code, you get all images from drawable folder. so create an array like this, `int[] imageArr=[R.drawble.image1.....];`
2. use one flag or counter, each and every time when the button is clicked increase that value,
3. For image setting, based on the counter/flag value get that image from image array based on that position. For ex. the `counter value=10` means, get `imageArr[10]`, now set this value as background.
4. Don't forget to check the array size and counter value, once the counter vaule is equal to array size set the counter value as 0.